# Confusing Java Class concept

Tags: java

New to java and a concept is confusing me a lot.

As a c++ programmer when we declare a class we can not have a property having an object of same class like lets say we have a class name Foo as belows

```
class Foo {
int age;
Foo someName;
}
```

the above code will give error. While in java i can do it. Is there a special reason behind it? And how does it happen. Any good read will be helpful.

Comment: I am not a C++ expert but I'm pretty sure that you can have a class with a member of the same type in C++ too.

Comment: Obviously you're a little confused with C++ concepts too.

Comment: following error pops up in C++ 

 error: field 'someName' has incomplete type
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you write `Foo someName` in Java, you're creating *a reference* to an object of type `Foo`. This is similar to writing `Foo& someName` in C++, which *is* allowed.

What is not allowed in C++ is for class `Foo` to have a member of type `Foo` (i.e. not `Foo&` or `Foo*`). If you think about it, this construct can't possibly make sense as it would require `sizeof(Foo)` to be infinitely large. This -- disallowed -- C++ construct has no direct Java equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

In Java when you declare `Foo someName`, the someName is really a reference to an object of class Foo.
So there is no problem to have a property referencing an object of the same type.

This is similar to how you can have `Foo& someName` in C++.

Answer (score 1):

Java stores objects as references. C++ doesn't. Therein is the difference.

With Java it does not need to know how much space to reserve for the Foo object. However in C++ the compiler needs to. So the C++ has an impossible task.

Comment: C++ just has to be told it's a reference.  See the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Thats because of an important between C++ and Java : in C++ , `Foo` above would be an object ; in Java `Foo` above is just a reference - not an object. ( You will have to write `Foo someref = new Foo()` for creating the object.